# Does Django process requests as queue?

Tags: django, django-models, queue

I am building a voting mechanism for a site. A similar one seen on Stackoverflow.

For instance, if user clicked up-arrow, `vote = True`. If he clicks again on it, `vote = None`. The app is working fine except if we submit votes very fastly.

We tried to click arrows very very fastly and see how voting is happening by logging the data. Unfortunately, we are seeing some misbehavior. By fast, I mean, clicking the arrow continuously without stopping for some seconds!

The expected log data should be like

```
vote=True
vote=None
vote=True
vote=None
..
```

But I observed it like

```
vote=True
vote=True
vote=None
vote=None
```

The observed log data mentioned as second case, seems to be a bit unordered.. 
This could mean that the requests received by django are not handled as a queue! Which in our case is a bit dangerous. Or database is taking some time to store and during that period another requests are handled which is causing the error.

I hope you are understanding my issue. So, I am wondering if you can let me know what's going on here and how to control it.

Comment: Did you use your own computer while experiment or some far-away computer on the other side of the Earth?

Comment: I have done locally. Why is that you are asking

Comment: Where do you print that? It can be case that client/browser sending request that way if you are not disabling the vote button immediately.

Comment: I have used `logging` module for logging data in a file. Actually, the client POST request contains data as `up`. Its the server which calculates whether to unvote referring to previous vote

Comment: A lot of what you are asking depends on things outside of Django. How is your server deployed? The development server, Apache/mod_wsgi, how many processes, & threads, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make assumptions about the order in which a browser sends (asynchronous) requests, the order in which they arrive at the server and the order in which they are handled by a single or multi-instance (threaded, worker) Django application.

So what you describe above is what you actually might expect. Doing synchronous requests may help a bit. The best option is probably to (asynchronously) wait for the server's response before allowing further clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You must be having a flow similar to this:

```
-> User clicks button
-> check if user has already voted up
-> if no:
    -> vote up request goes
    -> vote up after validation
    -> response is sent back to browser
-> else:
    -> vote none request goes
    -> remove the vote after validation
    -> response is sent back to browser
```

If you don't disable the button for the time when a request has already been sent and its response is awaited, then you will get into such situations.

Say, request1 was considered a vote up and request was sent.

Before request1's response came and user clicked again, then this request will also be considered as a vote up, which is not what you expect.

- You should either disable the button, just before making the ajax call and enable it again when the response is received.
- Or whenever user clicks, you should flip the button type i.e. make it vote-none for vote-up request and vice versa, even before making the ajax call. And when the ajax response is received, validate the previous action again. It will vary only in cases, when any validation fails on server side, like the user might not have permission to vote up.

You can see this happening in SO if you try to vote-up your own post. It first changes to vote-none mode and then later when the response is received from server, it changes back and also gives an error message.

PS: I tried to vote-up my own posts for educational purposes only ;)